# Holding page whilst apache down/restarted

Tags: apache-2.2, web-hosting, maintenance

Is there a way to have a holding page saying something along the lines of "The site is down don't panic" - just a static html page, nothing fancy, when apache is restarted or goes down?

If it is possible how would I go about doing it? Would it require a separate web server running which kicks in once apache goes down.

Any ideas or links to help out would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "correct" answer is that you should have a cluster with automated failover for unplanned outages, and shift your DNS to a new server for planned outages... But as you probably have noticed that is not always an option.

When I need a truly minimal web server to show offline messages and the like I usually use netcat:

```
while true; do nc -l -p 80 -q 1 < offline.html; done
```

It gets the job done with a minimum of fuzz and saves me from having to install additional software on the server. Just ctrl-c the script when you are done.

You could probably set it up start when apache goes down, but I done see the need. Random outages of apache are pretty much unknown in my environment.

Comment: Random outages of apache were previously unknown to us too, it's only in the past 2weeks that we've been seeing the load spike apparently randomly. This is more of a safeguard until we find the root cause.

Comment: +1 for netcat. Doesn't that offline.html file have to contain the HTTP response headers, too, though?

Comment: I think that I will use this approach as a temporary solution and long term probably go with nginx as a reverse proxy like vartec suggests

Comment: @SmallClanger Yes, you have to start the file with something like "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" to make browsers happy.

Comment: I tried that, but it didnt work. I created `offline.html`, stopped apache, then I started `while true; do nc -l -p 80 -q 1 < offline.html; done` as root and then called `http://localhost` but there was no page shown

Comment: but this worked: http://serverfault.com/a/444831/128892

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would like to ask is what kind of websites are you hosting? If its a small personal or corporate website that doesn't have many visitors, then don't worry about a little bot of downtime, or get a reliable hosting provider.

If you would really like to have a page then you could use a reverse proxy server to redirect the user while the web server is down.

Hope that helps, RayQuang

Comment: There is a corporate site on there and a couple of other smaller sites. The main site gets around 90K visitors a month.

Comment: Ok, In that case you would probably like to get a second server running with a reverse squid, and possibly a backup web server that you could redirect to in case the main one fails.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using reverse proxy, for example NgniX. Then on Apache being down, you'd get 502 or 504 error, which you can handle with you custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

it might be possible if you have an upstream cache (squid or similar) that can return a page while the server is restarting.

it would be a custom 10060 error page (or however squid references them)